# How to switch JBPM Business Central to debug logging

Tags: ldap, jbpm, wildfly-8, ldap-query, kie-workbench

I am building out a business central site.  Currently, I have it doing login/password, but then it gets to the authorization step and bombs.  I can't tell if i have an ldap group setting wrong or what.  It should be an easy fix, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to increase the logging level on business central itself.

i found the logging.properties in the wildfly/configuration folder, but when I map that to a configuration map (this is a k8's install) the server bombs saying it can't write to the logging.properties file.  Besides, that only sets it on the server itself, once the business-central.war begins, it switches back to app level INFO.

Where in the hell do I switch this thing to debug so i can try to figure out my authentication issue?  i can't even tell what logger its using

i was able to add this to my standalone.xml file

```
        <logger category="org.jboss.security">
            <level name="TRACE"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.jboss.as.security">
            <level name="TRACE"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="com.sun.jndi.ldap">
            <level name="TRACE"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.picketbox">
            <level name="TRACE"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.jboss.as.domain.management.security">
            <level name="TRACE"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.wildfly.security">
            <level name="TRACE"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.wildfly.elytron">
            <level name="TRACE"/>
        </logger>
```

and got more info, but what im really looking for are the queries and responses going to/from the ldap server.  Thats what i need to really debug this thing.  since i didn't write this thing, i don't even know what the values of the parameters are at the moment.

Comment: Did you try setting logger category "com.sun.jndi.ldap" to trace level and test?